# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my issue:
I am just trying to run basic tests, just to try this out, and I keep running into the exception: "**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL *(url here)* timed out after 60 seconds**".

I am using the most up to date Selenium, which is 3.3.0, and the most current Selenium Support, which is also 3.3.0.

I have set up the driver:

```
    public static class Driver
{
    public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

    public static void Initialize()
    {

        Instance = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
        Instance.Close();
    }
}
```

And I am running a basic test to login to a wordpress account, from a different class, to keep the test separated from the logic:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_LogIn()
    {
        WordPressLoginPage.GoTo();
        WordPressLoginPage.LoginAs("*******").WithPassword("*******").Login();
    }
```

And here is the methods that the test is calling:

```
    public class WordPressLoginPage
{
    private const string LoginUrl = "https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php";

    public static void GoTo()
    {
        Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(LoginUrl);
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        wait.Until(d => d.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().GetAttribute("id") == ("user_login"));
    }

    public static LoginCommmand LoginAs(string userName)
    {
        return new LoginCommmand(userName);
    }
}

public class LoginCommmand
{
    private readonly string _userName;
    private string _password;

    public LoginCommmand(string userName)
    {
        _userName = userName;
    }

    public LoginCommmand WithPassword(string password)
    {
        _password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        var loginInput = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("user_login"));
        loginInput.SendKeys(_userName);

        var passwordInput = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("user_pass"));
        passwordInput.SendKeys(_password);

        var loginSubmit = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("wp-submit"));
        loginSubmit.Submit();

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(65));

        wait.Until(d => d.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().GetAttribute("id") == ("search-component-1"));
    }
}
```

The exception tells me that the timeout happens here:

```
                loginSubmit.Submit();
```

and I can see that the page is still loading for probably more than two minutes after I started running it.

I have looked at other questions here regarding the same exception, but none of the answers from those seems to help here.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was coming across this issue in my framework, but not when individual tests were run. This was posing an issue when I was running multiple tests in parallel, and always on the `.Submit()` method with ChromeDriver.

In order to rectify this, I had to modify my scripts to click on a submit button instead. After this, my scripts ran fine.

For the record, I am using WebDriver and Support packages v3.4.0, ChromeDriver v2.29.0 and Chrome v58.0.3029.110.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. The issue occurred as a result of password pass through. The test team were all signing into their Virtual machines with the same credentials, Username: X and Password: Y. Similarity, the Virtual machine which stored the application we were testing against also had the same credentials.

However, at a particular point in time one of the developers changed Password from Y to Z. So the authentication for requesting a server response was failing in the background. You effectively need some form of an authentication service for your test project. See below for a good start point:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/using-selenium-webdriver-with-windows-authentication